# MacBook Pro 13-inch, upgrade 4 GB Ram to 8GB Ram

Tags: memory, macbook, upgrade

2.4 GHz Intel Core i5
4 GB 1333 MHz DDR3

Can I use 4Gb 1Rx8 Pc3L-12800S DDR3 1600Mhz to replace 2GB Ram DDR3 1333MHz?

Thank you

Comment: Without knowing the model year it is hard to say.  Please consult the apple website: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201165

Comment: MacBook Pro (13-inch, Late 2011), OS X Yosemite (10.10.5). I want to know if i can use DDR3 1600Mhz as the Mac Stated 'Your Mac contains 2 memory slots, each of which accepts a 1333 MHz DDR3 memory module. ' . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can use higher speed rated RAM above the rating specified by the manufacturer.  So long as the type is the same and the only difference is the maximum frequency supported by the RAM stick then it should work fine with the CPU.